# Why won't my simple c++ code compile? I get undeclared identifier?

Tags: c++

Why won't my simple c++ code compile? get undeclared identifier errors.

I can't see the problem

Thanks a lot

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    StateMachine<States,Triggers> sm;

    return 0;
}

enum States
{
    New,
    Complete
};

enum Triggers
{
    CreateNew,
    MoveToComplete
};

template <class TState, class TTrigger> class StateMachine
{
public:
    StateMachine();

};
```

Comment: Please post the error messages that you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to forward-declare the `StateMachine` class, otherwise the compiler does not now how to handle that identifier as it hasn't been told to him what it actually is, yet, or at least, that it exists.

```
template<class TState, class TTrigger> class StateMachine;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    StateMachine<States,Triggers> sm;

    return 0;
}

// ...

template <class TState, class TTrigger> class StateMachine
{
public:
    StateMachine();

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Either forward declare or move the `_tmain` to the bottom, also you've not provided an implementation for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler reads the code from top to bottom - it can only  understand things that have already been declared